# Sphinx ignores .rst files

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

`make html` and `sphinx-build 'source' 'build\html' -a -E` give the same results; an `.rst` file in `docs/source` I modified is being overridden when I add to `:exclude-members:` [here](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/blob/master/docs/source/deeptrain.util.rst#deeptrainutil_default_configs-module), generating [docs](https://dev-tg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deeptrain.util.html#deeptrain.util._default_configs._DEFAULT_REPORT_CFG) with said [member](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/blob/master/deeptrain/util/_default_configs.py#L53) present. Same behavior if simply wiping the entire .rst file clean; seems like the changes are being ignored entirely, and Sphinx is using some cached `.rst`'s instead (despite `-a -E`).

I don't recall having to do anything other than `make html`. I also tried preceding with `make clean`, and commenting out an [`app.connect`](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/blob/master/docs/source/conf.py#L207) which was noted to be potentially unstable. Is there some command to make Sphinx use the current `.rst` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are editing `.rst.txt` files in `build`, which are what's *generated* by Sphinx by reading `.rst` in `source`. Big brain.